# i want to convert records in a table into xml in sql server as shown below

Tags: sql-server, xml

I want to convert records in a table into XML in sql server as shown below.

Table

```
countryid   stateid siteid  value
1   1   1   11
1   1   2   22
1   2   1   55
1   2   2   66
2   1   1   111
2   1   2   222
2   2   1   555
2   2   2   666
3   1   1   100
3   1   2   200
3   2   1   500
3   2   2   600
```

I want to convert this data into XML as shown below.

```
<data>  
    <countrydata> 
        <countryid> 1 </countryid> 
        <stateid> 1 </stateid>
        <siteid> 1 </siteid>
        <value> 11 </value>
    </countrydata>
    <countrydata> 
        <countryid> 1 </countryid> 
        <stateid> 1 </stateid>
        <siteid> 2 </siteid>
        <value> 22 </value>
    </countrydata>
    <countrydata> 
        <countryid> 1 </countryid> 
        <stateid> 2 </stateid>
        <siteid> 1 </siteid>
        <value> 55 </value>
    </countrydata>
    <countrydata> 
        <countryid> 1 </countryid> 
        <stateid> 2 </stateid>
        <siteid> 2 </siteid>
        <value> 66 </value>
    </countrydata>
</data>
```

This XML is what I expect from records with countryid = 1..

Similarly I need different XML records with different countryids.

Comment: Have you tried anything so far by yourself? Any efforts?

Comment: your xml is invalid, you cannot have a space in your node `country data`

Comment: i tried FOR XML RAW ('data'), ELEMENTS;. it is converting all rows into single xml.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [FOR XML (SQL Server)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-za/library/ms178107.aspx)

> A SELECT query returns results as a rowset. You can optionally
>   retrieve formal results of a SQL query as XML by specifying the FOR
>   XML clause in the query.

Also, look through the examples found at [Use RAW Mode with FOR XML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-za/library/ms175140.aspx) and more specifically at

- [Example: Retrieving Product Model Information as XML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-za/library/bb510464.aspx)
- [Example: Renaming the  Element](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-za/library/bb522569.aspx)
- [Example: Specifying a Root Element for the XML Generated by FOR
  XML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522623.aspx)

How about something like

```
SELECT [countryid], [stateid], [siteid], [value]
FROM Table1
FOR XML RAW ('countrydata'), ELEMENTS, ROOT ('data')
```

### [SQL Fiddle DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/474f6/7)

Answer (score 0):

If you want the `XML` per `countryid`, You should `GROUP` your data based on `countryid` and then use a co-related sub-query to get the `xml` for that group using something like this.

```
;WITH yourtable as (
select 1 as countryid,1 as stateid,1 as siteid,1 as value
UNION ALL 
select 2 as countryid,1 as stateid,1 as siteid,1 as value
)
SELECT countryid, (SELECT countryid,stateid,siteid,value
FROM yourtable t2
WHERE t2.countryid = t1.countryid
FOR XML PATH('countrydata'),ROOT('data'),ELEMENTS,TYPE) as xmlval
FROM yourtable t1
GROUP BY countryid
```

Comment: Thanks..this approach helped me